# Reinstalling Windows 10 - how many digital licenses I have linked to my account

Tags: windows-10, license, reinstall

I need to reinstall Win 10 (after virus). After reading online, it looks like I would be able to do it easily since my system is activated with digital license.

However, I have a question. I have at least 3 PCs in my house with the same Microsoft account on them. Presumably, all of them have digital license linked to this same Microsoft account. I wonder if there is a centralized place to check all my digital licensed connected to my Microsoft account?

Comment: Digital license is tied to the hardware not your Microsoft account. No way to see what you want.

Comment: Each of your machines have a different digital entitlement.  You can link as many machines to your MS account.  Any machine linked to your MS account will be listed while viewing your MS account in a browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The digital license is a fingerprint of the hardware on which Windows 10 was installed.

As you have installed (and activated) Windows 10 on 3 PCs,
Microsoft now holds in its activation database three
digital licenses for each of the computers by their hardware.
Upon reinstalling Windows 10 on any of them, activation will
be immediate once Windows gets in touch with the Microsoft servers,
no matter which account was used to login, Microsoft account or
local account.

There is no connection between your Microsoft account and its
stored digital licenses, if none of these licenses was ever
installed on the current device.
Go to
[account.microsoft.com/devices](https://account.microsoft.com/devices)
to see a list of all the devices associated with your Microsoft account.

Comment: You said "*There is no connection between your Microsoft account & digital licenses*", but that's not quite true. According to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/reactivating-windows-after-a-hardware-change-2c0e962a-f04c-145b-6ead-fb3fc72b6665) on Microsoft.com "*In Windows 10 (version 1607 or later), it is essential to link your Microsoft account with the Windows digital license on your device. Linking your Microsoft account with your digital license allows you to reactivate Windows using the Activation troubleshooter whenever you make a significant hardware change.*"

Comment: @SimonE.: That's exactly what my answer says. I meant that a Microsoft account cannot be used to furnish a digital license to a new computer, just to validate licenses for registered existing devices.

Answer (score -1):

You can see them but only if you explicitly linked these licenses to your MS account like this, it's insufficient just to add the MS account to PC: [https://www.windowscentral.com/how-link-your-windows-10-product-key-microsoft-account](https://account.microsoft.com/billing/orders?period=AllTime&type=All&filterChangeCount=1)

Here is how to check the licenses in your MS account online:

1. Go to the https://account.microsoft.com/billing/orders?period=AllTime&type=All&filterChangeCount=1 URL, you will see entries like these

[image]

2. If you click "Show order details" you will see billing details (amount and shipping address) but no more. For OEM licenses tied to single PC neither the license key nor the serial number won't be showed, and these licenses doesn't appear in "Services & subscriptions" menu.

You have to blindly install Windows and add to it the MS account to check if the license works on your PC.